# Multithreading with Metal

Tags: swift, concurrency, metal

I'm new to Apple's Metal API and graphics programming in general. I'm slowly building a game engine of sorts, starting with UI. My UI is based on nodes each with their own list of child nodes. So if I have a 'menu' node with three 'buttons' as children, calling `render(:MTLDrawable:CommandQueue)` the menu will render itself to the drawable by committing a command buffer to the queue, and then call the same method for all of its children with the same drawable and queue, until the entire node tree has been rendered from top to bottom. I want a separate subthread to be spawned for he rendering of every node in the tree--can I just wrap each render function in a dispatch-async call? Is the command queue inherently thread-safe? What is the accepted solution for concurrently rendering multiple objects to a single texture before presenting it using Metal? All I've seen in any Metal tutorial so far is a single thread that renders everything in order using a single command buffer per frame, calling `presentDrawable()` and then `commit()` at the end of each frame.

**Edit**
When I say I want to use multithreading, it applies only to command encoding, not execution itself. I don't want to end up with the buttons in my theoretical menu being drawn and then covered up with the menu background as a result of bad execution order. I just want each object's render operation to be encoded on a separate thread, before being handed to the command queue.

Answer (score 2):

Using a separate command buffer and render pass for each UI element is extreme overkill, even if you want to use CPU-side concurrency to do your rendering. I would contend that you should start out by writing the simplest thing that could possibly work, then optimize from there. You can set a lot of state and issue a lot of draw calls before the CPU becomes your bottleneck, which is why people start with a simple, single-threaded approach.

Dispatching work to threads isn't free. It introduces overhead, and that overhead will likely dominate the work you're doing to issue the commands for drawing any given element, especially once you factor in the bandwidth required to repeatedly load and store your render targets.

Once you've determined you're CPU-bound (probably once you're issuing thousands of draw calls per frame), you can look at splitting the encoding up across threads with an `MTLParallelRenderCommandEncoder`, or multipass solutions. But well before you reach *that* point, you should probably introduce some kind of batching system that removes the responsibility of issuing draw calls from your UI elements, because although that seems tidy from an OOP perspective, it's likely to be a large architectural misstep if you care about performance at scale.

For one example, you could take a look at [this Metal implementation](https://github.com/warrenm/imgui/blob/master/examples/metal_example/imguiex-osx/imgui_impl_mtl.mm#L58) of a backend renderer for the popular [dear imgui](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui) project to see how to architect a system that does draw call batching in the context of UI rendering.